# Ubuntu 18.04 is taking too long to boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot

Clean Ubuntu Server 18.04 (not the live one) install (shell only).
Software RAID 1 has been configured during the installation (swap and ext4 partitions).

Boot up (time before login query) takes about 1 minute 30 seconds, which seems too long.

I'm far from Linux-savvy person, so I'm kind of at loss there.

What has been tried:

1. Raid sync seems to have been completed. `cat /proc/mdstat` output below:

   ```
   Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]  
   md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]  
     456254464 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]  
     bitmap: 2/4 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk  

   md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]  
     31982592 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]  

   unused devices: <none>
   ```
2. Top of `systemd-analyze blame`.

   ```
   1min 23.716s dev-md1.device  
   29.918s systemd-udev-trigger.service  
   26.608s systemd-journald.service  
   24.662s dev-hugepages.mount  
   23.128s sys-kernel-debug.mount  
   21.589s kmod-static-nodes.service  
   20.043s dev-mqueue.mount  
   18.501s systemd-remount-fs.service  
   15.882s lvm2-monitor.service  
   15.422s ufw.service  
   14.767s systemd-journal-flush.service  
   13.875s keyboard-setup.service  
   10.305s systemd-udevd.service  
    8.340s systemd-modules-load.service  
    8.209s accounts-daemon.service  
    7.074s systemd-networkd-wait-online.service  
    7.002s sysstat.service  
    5.804s postgresql@10-main.service  
    5.734s grub-common.service  
    ...
   ```
3. As from previous output there doesn't seem to be an obvious culprit, there's also a `systemd-analyze critical-chain` printout (red lines in bold)

   ```
   The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.  
   The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.  

   graphical.target @1min 55.465s  
   └─multi-user.target @1min 55.205s  
     └─getty.target @1min 54.946s  
       └─getty@tty1.service @1min 54.687s  
         └─system-getty.slice @1min 54.425s  
           └─setvtrgb.service @1min 53.629s +532ms  
             └─systemd-user-sessions.service @1min 51.782s +523ms  
               └─remote-fs.target @1min 51.260s  
                 └─remote-fs-pre.target @1min 50.998s  
                   └─iscsid.service @1min 45.455s +3.961s  
                     └─network-online.target @1min 45.164s  
                       └─systemd-networkd-wait-online.service @1min 31.353s +7.074s  
                         └─systemd-networkd.service @1min 29.288s +690ms  
                           └─network-pre.target @1min 28.243s  
                             └─ebtables.service @1min 22.874s +2.565s  
                               └─local-fs.target @1min 19.406s  
                                 └─var-lib-lxcfs.mount @1min 46.040s  
                                   └─local-fs-pre.target @1min 14.398s  
                                     └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @1min 10.981s +2.675s  
                                       └─kmod-static-nodes.service @44.534s +21.589s  
                                         └─systemd-journald.socket @34.813s  
                                           └─system.slice @4.660s  
                                             └─-.slice @2.777s
   ```

Is there anything to be done to improve the boot time?

Comment: Is this an actual Server or a personnal computer if the first then every thing is ok

Comment: @Kiwy it's a Server indeed. Thanks then, I've been quite worried there.

Comment: That's a great first question for a non-"Linux-savvy person". Welcome to [unix.se]!

Comment: @korli I can't be sure but I'm almost sure it's OK. Server are very long to boot most of the time because hardware component are slow to start making the bootvery long. You shouldn't get worry.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan thank you, you're very kind. Will do my best.